# Junit new instance vs Before

Tags: java, junit

Junit behavior is that it creates a new instance of a class for every test case.  The same way `@Before` is executed once before each test case.
Why do we need `@Before` when junit initializes the global variables for each test case. 
Check the example below. What is the difference between code1 and code2.
Ex:

***Code1***

```
public class MyTest{
        int count = 1;


    @Test
    public void test1(){
        count++;
        assertEquals(2, count); 
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        count++;
        assertEquals(2, count); 
    }
}
```

***Code2***

```
public class MyTest{
        private int count;

        @Before
        public void before(){
            count=1;
        }

        @Test
        public void test1(){
            count++;
            assertEquals(2, count); 
        }

        @Test
        public void test2(){
            count++;
            assertEquals(2, count); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `@Before` is useful if you want to initialize something that is more complicated than an `int`. For example, you can initialize database connections, service  classes, test data, properties, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that it isn't needed. Both of your examples are equivalent.

There's an argument for @Before being syntactically prettier than initialising in fields or a constructor. It also makes it obvious to someone who doesn't know the intricacies of JUnit that the values in a Before are set for each test method call.

Here's what Martin Fowler has to say on the matter: 
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html